# How to install/import React in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, atom-editor, typescript-typings

I try to get started with [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/). Since React is written in JavaScript, I install it using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com)

```
npm install --save react
```

I need type definitions for React. So I tried

```
$ typings install react --save
typings ERR! message Unable to find "react" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/react/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
```

I ran `typings search react` and found

```
NAME   SOURCE  HOMEPAGE                          DESCRIPTION  VERSIONS  UPDATED
react  dt      http://facebook.github.io/react/               2         2016-05-26T13:46:01.000Z
```

Hence, I explicitly specified the source

```
$ typings i dt~react --save
typings ERR! message Attempted to compile "react" as an external module, but it looks like a global module.
```

I can install React globally

```
typings install dt~react --save --global
```

but [Atom](https://atom.io/) still complains `Cannot find module 'react'` when I try to import React

```
import React from 'react'
```

How do you install React or configure TypeScript so that you can import React in TypeScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The React lib doesn't have a default export. So when you ask it to `import React`, it looks for a default export in that library. Unfortunately, it doesn't exist. Instead, import the whole contents and namespace in this way:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```